# Link my customer Analytics Account with My own Adwords Accounts

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api

I own Adwords manager Account where I create sub Account for each of my customers.
I would like to share those Adwords account with my customer analytics account by doing this process :

1 - My customers add my API account email (services@project.gserviceaccount.com) on their analytics account as admin user.

2 - I ask them to give me Analytics accountId & webPropertyId

3 - I use this request with Id of my Adwords account for customerId :

```
  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
  KEY_FILE_LOCATION, 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit')

  analytics = build('analytics', 'v3' , credentials=credentials)

  analytics.management().webPropertyAdWordsLinks().insert(
  accountId='123456',
  webPropertyId='UA-123456-1',
  body={
      'adWordsAccounts': [
          {
              'customerId': '123-456-7890'
          }
      ],
      'name': 'AdWords Link'
  }).execute()
```

I got this error :

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/177372348/webproperties/UA-121121420-1/entityAdWordsLinks?alt=json returned "User does not have sufficient permissions for this account.">
```

What I doing wrong ?

Comment: Given that you are getting an authorisation error, are you sure this approach is actually something Google supports? GA supports linking to AdWords (https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1704341?hl=en-GB&co=ADWORDS.IsAWNCustomer%3Dfalse). I don't know whether you can connect to more that one AdWords account, but I would guess they might be expecting this link to be in place and to be the specific mechanism you use for connecting up the data.

Comment: Actually I can do this process by hand (I ask my customer to add my google account as admin user in his analytics, and then I can create audience for him and use those audience in my personal Adwords account) but I can not find the way to do it through API. I think the problem is that my Api client oAuth of my analytics and my adwords account are not linked (same as it's not the same personne).  Can I use same API key in adwords api and analytics api ?

Comment: No idea, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033961), to link Adwords and Analytics accounts, a user needs to have Edit permissions on the Analytics property and Admin permissions on the Adwords account.

My guess would be that your service account user `services@project.gserviceaccount.com` does not have Admin rights in the Adwords account that you are trying to link.

You should be able to just add `services@project.gserviceaccount.com` as an administrator to your manager account, that way it will be granted admin in any linked Adwords account.

Comment: You have totally right, service account user services@project.gserviceaccount.com does not have Admin rights in the Adwords account. But when I tried to add this service as admin on my Adwords account, I my invitation stay pending, and I didn't get any email to confirm it. Is there mail box for service account user services@project.gserviceaccount.com where I can accept the invitation ?

Comment: Good point. If I get the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/authentication#oauth2_service_accounts) right, it's actually only possible using domain-wide delegation in a G Suite domain, and even then you'll have to use the service account to impersonate *another* user. So it might be easier to just use a dedicated, regular Google account in the first place.